# Add Hairline border to the bottom of UiToolbar in ios7

Tags: ios7, uitoolbar

I would like to remove the top 1px hairline display at the top, and add the 1px hairline to the bottom on a UiToolbar.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *uiToolbar;

// This removes the top hairline
uiToolbar.clipsToBounds = YES;

// How do I add a bottom hairline? (Should also resize automatically from portrait and landscape.)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello mownier,  You are correct.  I did not think about UiToolbar being a subclass of UiView (so all my google searches did not work)  If you write this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  Cheers.

Comment: Hi @user1256378, I write my comment as an answer. Glad to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Returning UIBarPositionTop from the -positionForBar: delegate method will also achieve the results you are looking for.

[iOS7 UIStatusBar blur not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920703/ios7-uistatusbar-blur-not-correct/18923011#18923011)